# How can I define a route in web.php to show 404 view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have several post requests in my web.php. If any user manually writes the URL, he/she gets an error because his/her http method is wrong. I want to manually send them the error 404 page if they try to do that.

What I want to do is this,

```
Route::post('/submit','Controller@apply');
Route::get('/submit', ); //do something here to return 404 page
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Route::get('/submit', function () { return abort(404); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this error in Exception handler provided by laravel where you can send to the 404 view. You can visit ***App\Exceptions\Handler***. Here if you just want to report the exception use **report method**, but as you want to show view for 404 , you need to use **render method**. Here in render we can convert exception into http response. Here you can use **use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException** not found exception and return 404. And you can use **abort**  helper to handle exception in handler. e.g.

```
 abort(404); //To create an exception (if manually creating exception)

//Hnadling exception in handler
public function render($request, Exception $e) {
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404-view', [], 500);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

here you can use **resources/views/errors/404.blade.php**.
For more information about error handling use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors)
Hope this helps